# Question in the proof of law of iterated logarithm in Billingslay.

Tags: probability-theory

From the page 156 of Probaility and measure(Billingslay)

I can't derive the highlighted argument. Why does the negative of the exponent asymptotically to that value?

Thanks in advance!

[image: LIL]

Comment: Please make your question self-contained (e.g. what is $M_n$, $\xi_k$,...).

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: $\log\log n_k=\log\log \theta^k=\log(k\log\theta)=\log k+\log\log\theta$

Comment: I already done it, but other terms still remain except for \theta^2logk